# How call a stub method on all connected clients with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm making a game in MeteorJS, where players can jump. I defined a method on my server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  jump: function () {
    // Send 'jump' event to all connected players
  }
});
```

If my client jumps, I want to inform other players that I "jumped" by doing something like

```
Meteor.call('jump');
```

I was hoping that the server could define a 'jump' method, which then calls the stubs on all connected clients. Is it only possible to call the stub on the client that called the original method?

I would need every player to listen to a 'jump' event, so they can add a physics force to their local player so it jumps in the air. Can I achieve something like this using methods? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with a message queue type collection (pub/sub). If you don't want to do it through the DB, you might try a project like this https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-streams which utilizes the existing Meteor websocket connection. The project isn't being maintained, but seems to work in 1.0.